# como puedo evitar que el resultado se repita?

Tags: c#

Evalúo si el numero 23 se encuentra en el array, si es así que saludo, sino adiós, ¿cómo puedo evitar que el resultado se repita?

lo que se quiere es que al solicitar los 7 numeros  se haga una busqueda en este caso el numero 23 si se encuentra dentro del arrrglo decir hola  en caso contrario decir adios.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ns = new int[7];
        
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese 7 numeros ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ns.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Igrese un numero");
            ns[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        Console.Write("busqueda de numero: \n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero a buscar: ");
        int numsearch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        
        for (int i = 0; i < ns.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ns[i] == 23)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HOLA");

            }

            else if (ns[i] != 23)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ADIOS");

            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: Muestra del resultado por pantalla]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Asi como esta, no sabemos ni que lenguaje es...

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Usa el boton [edit], explica mejor tu problema, y pone bien tu codigo, asi podemos ayudarte a solucionar un problema que hasta ahora, no vemos...

Comment: Cual es el supuesto resultado que se repite? los Console.WriteLine?? bueno, estan adentro del for.. si no queres que se repitan, dejalos afuera...

Comment: Tu pregunta no acaba de estar clara, ¿Cual es el resultado que no quieres que se repita?.  ¿Para que usarias la variable `numsearch`, que declaras y no usas despues para nada?

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios, soy un novato en esto y diculpa por no darme a entender.... lo que se quiere es que al solicitar los 7 numeros  se haga una busqueda en este caso el numero 23 si se encuentra dentro del arreglo decir hola  en caso contrario decir adios, pero lo que me esta pasando es que se rrepite el hola  muchas veces igual el adios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una variable booleana:

```
//declaramos la variable
boolean coincide = false;
//declaramos el bucle for
for (int i = 0; i < ns.Length; i++)
    {
        //si hay una coincidencia, ponemos la variable booleana a true
        if (ns[i] == 23)
        {               
            coincide = true;
        }
    }
//ahora evaluamos la variable, si está a true, imprimimos hola
if (coincide){
    Console.WriteLine("HOLA");
}
//si no está a true, imprimimos adios
else {
    Console.WriteLine("ADIOS");
}
```